# Spark job takes long time when using dynamic partitionOverwriteMode

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm currently using Scala Spark to data ingestion and transformation. I am currently using AWS EMR for this work. As a result of this process, I am writing and saving an output dataframe dynamically as parquet using the following line of code.

```
sparkSession.conf.set("spark.sql.sources.partitionOverwriteMode", "dynamic")
```

However, this df.write job takes around 2 hours to complete.

So, I looked into the code tried different configuration to find out what the issue is. It turns out that the dynamic partition is the issue. When I set the mode to 'overwrite' without the dynamic partition code I wrote above, the job only takes around 20mins.
Does anyone know why is the dynamic partition so inefficient in this case?

When I run the following code, it runs properly(takes around 20mins) in EMR.

```
df.repartition(col("date")).write.format("parquet").partitionBy("date").mode("overwrite").save()
```

When I run this code below, it takes around 1h 30mins.

```
sparkSession.conf.set("spark.sql.sources.partitionOverwriteMode", "dynamic")
datasets.dimPromoDS.repartition(col("date")).write.format("parquet").partitionBy("date").mode("overwrite").save()
```

I am using Spark 3.0.0.

Comment: Please provide the code associated to the question.

Comment: I've added the code. The real code has more complexity, but the code I wrote in the post is basically what the code is doing. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Probably with the dynamic option Spark has to check if your current data is already in each partition